# Is there any way to prevent a keyboard to show up in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

My activity has a single text field, which is editable, I want it so that when the activity is started the keyboard doesn't automatically start up, it should come up only when the user clicks on the editTiext field.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest file add this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`to your `activity`!

Comment: I tried to but it says I have to wait 3 minutes to accept it!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like when your activity starts your `TextView` (since you said text field I suppose you have a `TextView` but the property exists on other views as well) receives automatically `focus`. Try looking at the `TextView` properties to find one that is about the object receiving focus.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public static void hideKeyboard(Context mContext){
       //Hide a keypad write down on onCreate
      ((Activity) mContext).getWindow()
      .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}

public static void showKeyboard(Context mContext,EditText edittext){
    //Show a Keyboard when you click on Edittext
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.showSoftInput(edittext, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
}
```